# odd batch file programming error :Invalid argument/option: - 'eq'

Tags: windows, batch-file, tasklist

I have a line of BAT code written like this:

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq WerFault.exe"|find /C "WerFault.exe" > temp.txt
```

It went on well for quite a few days but suddenly I got this error message:

```
error :Invalid argument/option: - 'eq'
```

The code hasn't been changed before and after this error message, I can't figure out what's the problem.

Comment: you'll receive the same result if there are no quotes in tasklist command call.Looks like something connected of how the command is called.Provide more code.

Comment: @npocmaka, you need the double-quotes around the `/FI` filter specification (at least for Win7 x64). @Mofi, it cannot be a `PATH` issue as the error message is produced by the `tasklist` command.

Comment: Does it work as expected on another, "known good" computer? A direct copy and paste of your code as-is to a console, *and* in a batch file, works perfectly and as expected for me. Maybe the actual tasklist and find executables, or something else, broke--in the filesystem?

Comment: I just found that `tasklist /fi “memusage gt 100000”` was throwing that error in git bash on windows. I ran the same command in cmd as admin and it worked fine. Probably has something to do with the way git bash is processing it.

Answer (score 6):

You, or people coming here from a search, may have been trolled by text encoding madness and the borderline sabotaging behavior of cmd.exe, combined with [websites such as this one](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-fix-svchostexe-errors-and-problems-with-high-cpu-usage/).

What they did:

1. Omit one quotation mark
2. Replace the other quotation mark with **Unicode character 201c**

What's probably going on:

- The user copy-pastes the line and gets an error
- The user notices the missing quotation mark and adds it
- **It now looks identical to the other quotation mark**, so there's no way to see what is going on.
- Not only does it look identical, **copy-pasting it back out, such as to Stackoverflow, replaces it with a standard, undirected double quotation mark!** In other words, it is indistinguishable from the correct symbol even when copying it back out of the window for analysis!
- The above is true even for copy-paste within cmd (which *conveniently* doesn't work with standard hotkeys) but **not** for bringing back a line via the up-key.

What I have once again learned from this:

### Do not trust what you see when Unicode is involved.

Also, cmd.exe is generally not very safe or sane. When in doubt, re-type the command manually.

This might not be the cause here, but if others come here for the same reason as I, maybe this answer will save them a few minutes.

Comment: Well put; the command copied properly for me, but I see how that effect could happen to someone else.

Comment: 5 years ago I submitted this question, shortly after this question I quit IT industry. Although being a lame coder back then, I miss that good/bad old days. Thank you!